# Accessing rows in XDF File

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I am solving the exercise 2 from https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/20773_Analyzing-Big-Data-with-Microsoft-R/blob/master/Instructions/20773A_LAB_AK_04.md. The code creates the function which calculates the zone time etc. I do not understand why one can access variables and rows in the XDF File by for example  `departureYear <- dataList[[departureYearVarIndex]][i]` inside the function, but if I try to do the same just from the subset file:

```
rxOptions(reportProgress = 1)
flightDelayDataSubsetFile <- "\\\\LON-RSVR\\Data\\flightDelayDataSubset.xdf"
flightDelayDataSubset <- rxDataStep(inData = mergedFlightDelayData,
    outFile = flightDelayDataSubsetFile, overwrite = TRUE,
    rowSelection = rbinom(.rxNumRows, size = 1, prob = 0.005)
)
```

like e.g. `flightDelayDataSubset[[1]][1]` it tells me "Error...this S4 class is not subsettable".

How to access the elements in XDF file? Why does it work in the function, but not manually for an existing file? I probably ask the wrong question because I do not understand how this function works. The functions argument dataList is given as a vector of XDF File Columns

```
transformFunc = standardizeTimes,
        transformVars = c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth", "DepTime", "ActualElapsedTime", "OriginTimeZone")
```

. In the function it is treated as a list [[]] instead `dataList[[arrivalTimeVarIndex]]`. I am totally confused how it works. The question is probably, how this function knows which argument relates to which argument in the

```
transformVars = c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth", "DepTime", "ActualElapsedTime", "OriginTimeZone")?
```

The function looks like this:

```
standardizeTimes <- function (dataList) {
    # Check to see whether this is a test chunk
    if (.rxIsTestChunk) {
        return(dataList)
    }

# Create a new vector for holding the standardized departure time
# and add it to the list of variable values
departureTimeVarIndex <- length(dataList) + 1
dataList[[departureTimeVarIndex]] <- rep(as.numeric(NA), times = .rxNumRows)
names(dataList)[departureTimeVarIndex] <- "StandardizedDepartureTime"

# Do the same for standardized arrival time
arrivalTimeVarIndex <- length(dataList) + 1
dataList[[arrivalTimeVarIndex]] <- rep(as.numeric(NA), times = .rxNumRows)
names(dataList)[arrivalTimeVarIndex] <- "StandardizedArrivalTime"
departureYearVarIndex <- 1
departureMonthVarIndex <- 2
departureDayVarIndex <- 3
departureTimeStringVarIndex <- 4
elapsedTimeVarIndex <- 5
departureTimezoneVarIndex <- 6

# Iterate through the rows and add the standardized arrival and departure times
for (i in 1:.rxNumRows) {
    # Get the local departure time details
    departureYear <- dataList[[departureYearVarIndex]][i]
    departureMonth <- dataList[[departureMonthVarIndex]][i]
    departureDay <- dataList[[departureDayVarIndex]][i]
    departureHour <- trunc(as.numeric(dataList[[departureTimeStringVarIndex]][i]) / 100)
    departureMinute <- as.numeric(dataList[[departureTimeStringVarIndex]][i]) %% 100
    departureTimeZone <- dataList[[departureTimezoneVarIndex]][i]

    # Construct the departure date and time, including timezone
    departureDateTimeString <- paste(departureYear, "-", departureMonth, "-", departureDay, " ", departureHour, ":", departureMinute, sep="")
    departureDateTime <- as.POSIXct(departureDateTimeString, tz = departureTimeZone)

    # Convert to UTC and store it
    standardizedDepartureDateTime <- format(departureDateTime, tz="UTC")
    dataList[[departureTimeVarIndex]][i] <- standardizedDepartureDateTime

    # Calculate the arrival date and time
    # Do this by adding the elapsed time to the departure time
    # The elapsed time is stored as the number of minutes (an integer)
    elapsedTime = dataList[[5]][i]
    standardizedArrivalDateTime <- format(as.POSIXct(standardizedDepartureDateTime) + minutes(elapsedTime))

        # Store it
        dataList[[arrivalTimeVarIndex]][i] <- standardizedArrivalDateTime
    }

    # Return the data including the new variables
    return(dataList)
}

flightDelayDataTimeZonesFile <- "\\\\LON-RSVR\\Data\\flightDelayDataTimezones.xdf"
flightDelayDataTimeZones <- rxDataStep(inData = flightDelayDataSubset,
    outFile = flightDelayDataTimeZonesFile, overwrite = TRUE,
    transformFunc = standardizeTimes,
    transformVars = c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth", "DepTime", "ActualElapsedTime", "OriginTimeZone"),
    transformPackages = c("lubridate")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My [dplyrXdf](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf) package lets you index and subset Xdf files like they are data frames. Specifically it defines `[[` and `$` methods to extract columns from the file (but not `[`, because of implementation issues)

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi, could you tell me, how would I access e.g. the first column from "\\\\LON-RSVR\\Data\\flightDelayDataTimezones.xdf"? flightDelayDataTimeZonesFile[[1]]?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, after two days of "fighting" with my functions, I understood how it works. Also the dplyrXdf package is very handy to use!